# CH32V203 Jumping to bootloader from software

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, bootloader, riscv

I'd like to enter to bootloader in the RISC-V MCU from software instead of the BOOT0 pin.

From the referenece manual when the BOOT0 pin is high the flash containing the internal bootloader is mapped to the adress 0. Bellow is the table from the reference manual.

[image]

I've tried to execute the bootloader with the folowing code

```
typedef void (*BootloaderFunction)(void);
#define BOOTLOADER_ADDRESS 0x1FFF8000
int main(void)
{

    BootloaderFunction bootloader = (BootloaderFunction)BOOTLOADER_ADDRESS;
    bootloader();

    while(1)
    {
    }
}
```

However I get a hard fault when it executes.
I've also tried debugging it with stepping through instructions and the cpu does jump to the bootloader address. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Just a guess: bootloader loads and executes code which calls bootloader. If bootloader or some other runtime part initializes stack pointer, you get infinite loop. If stack pointer remains untouched, you get stack overflow.

Comment: Bootloader is linked against the address 0, and I seriously doubt that it is positionally independent. It is just impossible to run it at the flash addresses.